# A new database named ".serversidedebugger" has suddenly appeared after restarting MySQL server

Tags: mysql

what is the .serversidedebugger and how to remove or disappear?

i want to remove it if not required for MySQL server.

schema name is - .serversidedebugger and tables found- debugcallstack,debugdata,debuglocker,debugsscop,debugsessions,debuggtbl, any many more.

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio Debugger database which allows to debug MySQL stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql for Visual Studio plugin has a feature for debugging stored procedures, which according to its [documentation](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/visual-studio-en.pdf):

> The debugger recreates at the start of each debug session a serversidedebugger database in your
> server.

Since the database is recreated each time you run a debug session, it is safe to remove it.